# Remove spacing between items in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using a RecyclerView to show a List of Items and I need to remove the default spacing between Items. I'm trying to set a RecyclerView.LayoutParams and set margins to zero on my LinearLayoutManager but didn't work!

Here is my code:

**layout/fragment_recycler.xml**

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/freshSwipeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/freshRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**layout/cardview_recycler.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <mypackagename.ui.view.RecyclingImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img_no_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_smallest" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerFragment.java**

```
    /* Setting Layout Manager */
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mLayoutManager.canScrollVertically();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

I need help...

Comment: Why do you define but never use params in your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just remove the cardview in your **layout/cardview_recycler.xml**, android puts that spacing that you don't want

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <mypackagename.ui.view.RecyclingImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_no_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_smallest" />
</LinearLayout>
```

everything else stays as it is

Comment: Is there no way to adjust the spacing which the card view puts? I want to keep the spacing, but I don't want like 20dp space?

Comment: why cardview adds spacing?

Answer (score 8):

Give android:layout_height = **wrap_content** instead of match_parent to your item root layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       -------
       -------
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case below code worked

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/freshRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the line `setVisibiilty(gone)`

after removing it works perfectly .

Answer (score -4):

Try to use **cardElevation=0dp**. This should remove the extra spacing between recyclerview items.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
   app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <mypackagename.ui.view.RecyclingImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_no_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_smallest" />
 </LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView />
```

Comment: I made the following changes in carview to reduce gap between RecycleView Items.   app:cardElevation="0dp"
app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"